# Fontawesome without serif font

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<a href="#home">
 <i class="fas fa-chart-bar fa-lg">
  <span class="card-text card-textWithIcon">serif font</span>
 </i>
</a>
```

it shows an image and a short text. It works fine but the text is in a serif font. How can I switch to a sans serif font?

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Fontawesome 5.8.1

Edit 1: 
I added

```
font-family:sans-serif !important
```

to the .fa class. But then the icon is visible as an rectangle (which is wrong).

Edit 2:
I added two new classes:

```
.span {
    font-family:Sans-Serif
}

.sansserif {
    font-family:Sans-Serif
}
```

and added the .sansserif to the span-element:

```
<span class="card-text card-textWithIcon sansserif">serif font</span>
```

But this did not work.

Solution: see second comment from elveti
"You should not add additional content into your  *icon. Put it afterwards, like* serif font – elveti 2 mins ago"

Comment: You should not add additional content into your `<i>` icon. Put it afterwards, like `<i class="fas fa-chart-bar fa-lg"></i><span class="card-text card-textWithIcon">serif font</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Font Awesome as font family for all `i` tags then `Sans-Sarif` for everything else or what you want to use it for

```
i.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free' !important;
  font-style: none
}

* {
  font-family:Sans-Serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method. You can set the font-family to root element or `body` tag.

```css
body {
  font-family:Sans-Serif;
}
a .fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
.card-text {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<a href="#home">
 <i class="fas fa-chart-bar fa-lg">
  <span class="card-text card-textWithIcon">serif font</span>
 </i>
</a>
```